# Execute script to inside another bash script

Tags: bash

On my server I try run:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH="/SANCFS/stats/scripts/"

for (( i=6;i<=8;i++ ));
do
   echo "Running $i"

   exec "/SANCFS/stats/scripts/load_cdrs.sh --debug --config /SANCFS/stats/scripts/iquall-mm4-cdr.cfg --date '2018-10-0"$i"' >> /home/stats/201810/load_cdrsIMRMM4-0"$i".ok 2>>/home/stats/201810/load_cdrsIMRMM4-0"$i".err"
done
```

And the result is:

cannot execute: No such file or directory

Your help, how edit/modify to run successfully ?

Comment: Why are you enclosing the while command line after `exec` in double quotes?  If you do that, shell will treat the whole thing as the command name.  Remove outer the double quotes and you should be good.

Comment: Unless you are certain that you don't need things like /usr/bin in your PATH, you almost certainly do not want to reset the PATH like this.  If you want to add /SANCFS/stats/scripts/ to your path, write something like `PATH="$PATH:/SANCFS/stats/scripts/"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
$ exec "echo "hello world""
bash: exec: echo hello: not found
```

Running a command in `bash` does not require adding `exec` or quotes:

```
$ echo "hello world"
hello world
```

Additionally, you are using `$i` in single quotes in one case, and you're overwriting the shell search path `PATH` for seemingly no reason. Applied to your example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=6;i<=8;i++ ));
do
   echo "Running $i"

  /SANCFS/stats/scripts/load_cdrs.sh --debug --config /SANCFS/stats/scripts/iquall-mm4-cdr.cfg --date "2018-10-0$i" >> /home/stats/201810/load_cdrsIMRMM4-0"$i".ok 2>>/home/stats/201810/load_cdrsIMRMM4-0"$i".err
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `exec`. That replaces the current process with the process that runs the specified command, so you won't repeat the loop. Just execute the command normally.

And the argument to `exec` shouldn't be all inside a single quoted string. Maybe you're confusing it with `eval`?

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH="/SANCFS/stats/scripts/"

for (( i=6;i<=8;i++ ));
do
   echo "Running $i"

   /SANCFS/stats/scripts/load_cdrs.sh --debug --config /SANCFS/stats/scripts/iquall-mm4-cdr.cfg --date 2018-10-0"$i" >> /home/stats/201810/load_cdrsIMRMM4-0"$i".ok 2>>/home/stats/201810/load_cdrsIMRMM4-0"$i".err
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace exec with dot ( . ) 
If you try the 5 options, you should see the different options

```
$ exec /bin/bash

$ /bin/bash
$ . /bin/bash
$ ./bin/bash
$ /bin/bash /bin/bash
```